# Update database through php form

Tags: php, sql

The code executes normally but when the update is selected by the user , the code don't do what it is supposed to do i.e. to update database using a query. I have tested the query, it's working fine.
 I have looked other question discussing the same thing, but I don't find solution to my problem in those questions.

```
<?php
    $s_course = $_POST['course_id'];
    ...
    $conn=oci_connect("****" , "****" , "****");
    $sql=oci_parse($conn, "select * from evaluate where Course_ID ='$s_course'and Section = '$s_section' and Exam_Type = '$s_exam_type' and Exam_ID = '$s_exam_num' and Roll_Number = '$s_roll_no'");
    oci_execute($sql);
    $row=oci_fetch_array($sql);
    echo "<table align='center'>";
    echo "<tr class='header'><td>Roll No.</td><td>Marks Scored</td><td>Attendence</td><td>New Marks</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>$row[0]</td><td>$row[4]</td><td>$row[5]</td><td>";
?>
    <form method="post" action="update_student_marks.php">
        <input type="number" name="newmarks"></input>
    </form>
<?php
    echo  "</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
?>
    <form method="post" action="update_student_marks.php">
        <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></input>
    </form>
<?php

    if(isset($_POST["update"]))        // not coming in even if 'Update' key is pressed
    {
        $sql=oci_parse($conn, "update evaluate set Marks = '$_update_marks' where Course_ID ='$s_course' and Section = '$s_section' and Exam_Type = '$s_exam_type' and Exam_ID = '$s_exam_num' and Roll_number = '$s_roll_no'");
        oci_execute($sql);

        $sql=oci_parse($conn, "commit");
        oci_execute($sql);
    }
?>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: test with this `or die(oci_error($conn))`

Comment: When you're using a HTML `<form>`, you need to have all the inputs between the opening and closing tags. At the moment, your update form contains nothing but a submit button

Comment: where the variables are defined ?????

Comment: It all looks right. Let's do a sanity check:

`if(isset($_POST["update"]))        // not coming in even if 'Update' key is pressed
    {
        $sql=oci_parse($conn, "update evaluate set Marks = '$_update_marks' where Course_ID ='$s_course' and Section = '$s_section' and Exam_Type = '$s_exam_type' and Exam_ID = '$s_exam_num' and Roll_number = '$s_roll_no'");
        oci_execute($sql);

        $sql=oci_parse($conn, "commit");
        oci_execute($sql);
    } else {
        var_dump($_POST);
    }`

Comment: @StaticVoid , 'if' works individually, but when I use it in this way then it don't work, I don't understand why.

Comment: @user790454, I have variables defined but I havent included them in the question

Comment: So the code inside the "if" does get accessed, or the else block runs?

Comment: yes it does, but in this code it don't get accessed. I thought if there was a problem in the place I have inserted 'if' block.

Comment: Your if statement is correct in checking for the existence of the update button. You need to test your first variable and see what that prints, it will reveal the scope and value of your variables:

`var_dump($sql);`